# Firebase for flutter android app build.gradle error

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am a kid developer and new to programming, i was setup  of my android app to firebase  database using Firebase assistant in visual studio, when i run the project, i got and error message as Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

`Here is my app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_travel"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_travel"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
 plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

dependencies {
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')

}
```

And here is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5"


        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my flutter app is not run and help me

Answer (score 0):

From what you explained I understood it as the flutter is not recognizing your project as a Flutter project. This might be due to the structure of your project or misconfiguration.To resolve this issue, you should ensure that your project structure aligns with the typical Flutter project structure, which includes a pubspec.yaml file at the root directory.

1. Make sure the pubspec.yaml is in the root directory of the project where the android and ios folders are also seen
2. Ensure you're running Flutter commands from the root directory of your project. If you're using Firebase Assistant in Android Studio, make sure you're executing the commands in the correct directory.
3. Ensure that Flutter SDK is installed correctly and added to your system's PATH variable. You can verify this by running flutter doctor command in your terminal to see if there are any issues reported.
4. Double-check your Flutter configuration in android/build.gradle and android/app/build.gradle files to ensure they are correctly set up. The provided configuration seems correct, but it's worth verifying.
5. Sometimes, simply restarting your IDE (like Android Studio) can resolve configuration-related issues.

Happy coding